# Generating com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.types.StringSchema with "contentEncoding": "base64" in JAVA

Tags: java, jsonschema, binary-data

We have a Rest API which allows clients to GET back some binary content (e.g. Image) We are using JsonSchema to help describe the API in question so I want to built out a JsonSchema representing that content.

Looking through json-schema.org's recommendation here:
[https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/non_json_data.html?highlight=binary][1]

The relevant JsonSchema can be represented as the following `StringSchema`:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "contentEncoding": "base64",
  "contentMediaType": "image/png"
}
```

- Searching around i found a similar question with solution but it's related to `C#` and relevant implementation of the underlying `SchemaGenerator`:
  https://bytemeta.vip/repo/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/284 But inspired by that I also tried looking through the `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchemaGenerator` but also was not able to figure out how to built the relevant schema using that either.
- I also tried creating a `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.types.StringSchema` directly but was also not able to add either "`contentEncoding`" or "`contentMediaType`" keywords to the generated `StringSchema`.

So was wondering if anyone else happened to have any pointers on what can be done in this situation in order to generate the JsonSchema we desire?

Comment: I don't tend to see these keywords used very often. They are not validaiton keywords, and code generation tends to only cover the most basic of use cases. I would create an issue on the tooling's repo.